# Command to select to beginning or end of code block/paragraph in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, navigation, textselection

So I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114166) on GitHub which discusses cursor navigation by code block/paragraph.  Is there a related functionality to simultaneously select from the current cursor position to the end or beginning of the next block as well?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting can be accomplished by adding `"select": true,` to the `"args"` list in the keybindings described in the linked GitHub issue.  So the final result would look like this (adding `shift` to the keybinding to differentiate it from the paragraph navigation command):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus", 
    "args": {
        "to": "nextBlankLine",
        "by": "wrappedLine",
        "select": true,
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+up",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus", 
    "args": {
        "to": "prevBlankLine",
        "by": "wrappedLine",
        "select": true,
    }
}
```